# cannot get whole number attribute from entity with QueryExpression

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Basicly, I was trying to get a whole number attribute from the entity to assign a value but when I check in debug, only "new_name" and "new_firmid" attributes shown.

```cs
Entity entity = new Entity("new_firm");

ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression("new_name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Firm");
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(entity.LogicalName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_name","new_number");
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(condition);

EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

collection.Entities[0].Attributes["new_number"] = (int) collection.Entities[0].Attributes["new_number"] + 10;

service.Update(collection.Entities[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the attribute `new_number` inside the entity attributes because the value is empty.

you need to check this condition before applying the new value, something like:

```cs
if (collection.Entities[0].Contains("new_number")) {
   collection.Entities[0].Attributes["new_number"] = (int)collection.Entities[0].Attributes["new_number"] + 10;
} else {
   collection.Entities[0].Attributes["new_number"] = 10; // assuming that empty equals 0
}
```